# changing text color on one sheet and having automatically update the other sheets

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have 13 sheets in my workbook. On page 1 in cell C1 it has the name of a person "John". Is there a way when I change the name to "Steve" and change the color of type to red that it will change automatically on the rest of the sheets in the workbook? I have no trouble getting the name changed to "Steve", it is getting the color of the text changed on the other sheets that I am having difficulty with.

Comment: How are you changing the name?

Answer (score 1):

I guess it is not possible (without vba) to do this for the action of the color-change. But you can do this for the action of the name-change.

Assuming this is Excel 2007 or 2010 there is an option to do this via conditional formatting.
As I dont have an Excel here in English, i try to explain it without screenshots.

Select the cell which should change to red as soon as you type in Steve instead of John in your other cell. Got to conditional formatting. There is an option to change the layout of the cell based on a custom formula which you can give in. 
Here you can give in a when-formula which is "true" if you type in steve in your Name-Cell and base your formatting on that true or false value the entered formula gives back.

Hope that helps.
cheers!